# Assign index value by bool vector get confusing result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Here is the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,5,6,1,2,7,2,0,2,4]})
```

I want to replace the elements that are larger than 3, so I do this:

```
df['a'][df['a']>3] = [9,99,999,9999]
```

I got the wrong result:

```
     a
0    2
1   99
2  999
3    1
4    2
5   99
6    2
7    0
8    2
9   99
```

The result that I want is this:

```
      a
0     2
1     9
2    99
3     1
4     2
5   999
6     2
7     0
8     2
9  9999
```

However, when the replacement is strings, the result seems right:

```
df['a'][df['a']>3] = ['a','b','c','d']
   a
0  2
1  a
2  b
3  1
4  2
5  c
6  2
7  0
8  2
9  d
```

Why this happens and how can I make it right? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). Try this:

```
df.loc[df['a']>3, 'a'] = [9,99,999,9999]

#       a
# 0     2
# 1     9
# 2    99
# 3     1
# 4     2
# 5   999
# 6     2
# 7     0
# 8     2
# 9  9999
```

Comment: Thank you so much !